# I accidentally designed my webpages on zoom value of 80% on Chrome. How do I modify my CSS to adjust to 100% zoom?

Tags: css, reactjs

As you can see below, this is how it looked while I was designing the page 
80% :
[image]

After finding out that I was on 80% all along, I had completed 90% of my CSS
100% :
[image]

What can I do to my CSS to scale it in such a way that it looks like the first image at 100% zoom level?

Comment: You have to do it manually by changing the CSS.

Comment: so you want to scale down all your css 20%?

Answer (score 0):

Check the meta attribute 'initial-scale' maybe it can help you.
Otherwise i'm with Adesh just change everything manually. At the end you have a cleaner result.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the zoom attribute in css -- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/zoom

```
body {
 zoom: 100%
}
```